# How to heapify array of types in julia

Tags: arrays, heap, julia

In `julia` I have created given type:

```
type Event
  clientNumber
  time
end
```

Then I created an array which elements are of type `Event`:

```
e1 = Event(1, 12)
e2 = Event(2, 13)
e3 = Event(3, 2)
events = [e1, e2, e3]
```

My question is: how to heapify this array by field `time` of type `Event`? If it was just simple array of `Int's` it would look just like this:

```
arr = [4, 3, 21, 54, 1]
Collections.heapify!(arr)
```

but I don't know how to compare these events in heap.

Code:

```
Collections.heapify!(events)
```

returns error:

```
MethodError: no method matching isless(::Event, ::Event)
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but one way is to define the method Julia is complaining about: `Base.isless(a::Event,b::Event) = isless(a.time,b.time)`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :)

Comment: I've added an answer, to give this question closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is to define the method Julia is complaining about, like so:

```
Base.isless(a::Event,b::Event) = isless(a.time,b.time)
```

Now, `Collections.heapify!(events)` should work.